# Birt - How to Set Data Source Timeout?

Tags: birt

One of my JDBC data sources in a Birt report points to a MySQL server that goes down every so often (long story)

But when it does go down Birt/Eclipse freezes for 5+ minutes.  Is there a way to lower the timeout value?  I look everywhere in Eclipse and I haven't found it.

Comment: I am running some performance testing using SQL trace and noticed that queries that fail (syntax type errors) make 5 attempts to run, before BIRT gives up.  You might try to write something in the 'beforeOpen' Script of the 'data source' to ping the database before attempting to run the report. see here for a bit about scripting.  http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportScripting.php

Answer (score 2):

I ended up clicking on the properties (advanced section) of the data set instead and I could set a field called "&Query Time Out (in seconds)" there.  It seemed to work for my needs.

Update:
It seemed like this solution was working yesterday, but now Eclipse is still freezing and not using the timeout.

Comment: If you are able to validate that "&Query Time Out (in seconds)" works as expected when the SQL sever is known to be down.  Please post the confirmation. "seemed to work for my needs" implies it has not had a real life test yet.

Comment: While the server is up, I was able to set the TimeOut (whole seconds only, .5 does not work) and consitently get good results. I used values from 1 to 10 seconds, and SQL Server Profilier showed a duration of about a 1/10 of second past the set TimeOut.

Answer (score 0):

This post http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/22435-blank-report-after-a-long-time-in-web-viewer/ talks about changing the "session-timeout" of Apache. In the example they wanted longer time. But if all your reports run quick, you should be able to lower the value.

Answer (score 0):

Report Design > Data Set Editor > JDBC Data Set > The time out limit (secods)

[image]